# Does Android support any other database system other than SQLite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have been searching and have found out, that android supports only SQLite databse and no other. Is this true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The Android library provides native support to only SQLite. Of course, this doesn't mean you absolutely can't use other databases on Android; if you need to use other databases, you'll have to either look for already-existing third-party libraries(1), or roll out your own API.

(1) Careful there: If you look for third-party libraries, make sure they're built specifically for Android, since Android includes only a subset of the Java standard library. If they're not specifically built for Android, there's a possibility that the libraries won't work due to missing classes.

Comment: Thanks and do you know of some 3rd party libraries for android?

Comment: I am very sure they exist, but I am not aware of any, except for Amazon's SimpleDB service.    First, it's probably helpful to know what database you're planning on using. Secondly, it's not a bad idea to look around the official websites of those databases to see if they have any libraries. And finally, if that fails, you can try a Google  search to see if anyone has taken a shot at it.

Comment: I have been searching several hours via Google and no result. If I had found something on Google, I wouldn't have writtern here. But thanks for pointing out Amazons's simple DB, I will look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Android Supports H2 Database too. please check it out with below link,

http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#android

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Though SQLite is natively supported on Android and is most used database, there exists other options as well. Listing a few of them below;

**Realm:**
Reactive, concurrent, and lightweight, allowing you to work with live, native objects.
https://realm.io/docs/

**H2:**
Full Unicode support including UPPER() and LOWER().
Streaming API for BLOB and CLOB data.
Fulltext search.
Multiple connections.
http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#android

**CouchDB:**
Full CRUD and query functionality, NoSQL, lightweight, embedded, syncable
https://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/

**LevelDB:**
Lightweight and single purpose (not an SQL database)
http://leveldb.org/
Java wrapper: https://github.com/hf/leveldb-android

I am not including BerkeleyDB here as (AFAIK) it needs OS level changes to be made to replace the SQLite routines. More info here https://blogs.oracle.com/berkeleydb/now-you-can-build-berkeley-db-into-your-android-apps

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is the only one I ever actually see being used. I would suggest using it because it is lightweight and free to use. When developing your App, lightweight is key, memory is limited on these devices! Is there any specific reason why you wouldn't want to use SQLite? Any feature that you're looking for that you don't see in SQLite?

Comment: Just to weigh in on this conversation, of course there is a reason. A really big one, if you want to store massive data that changes on a regular basis and have user access it you would need a server model which SQL light does not provide. For example an app that finds local restaurants with details like ratings and pictures. This would be way too complicated to store and maintain on the clients phone. Just the size of it would be prohibitive... Or as mentioned above the amazon database sql would not be able to accomplish putting amazon on a phone impossible.