# Limit of database on Android

Tags: android, database

I am new to the Android databases, I'm just now learning about databases.  I have some questions.

1.What is the maximum limit(size) of database that an application has access to.

2.If I'm using an application that uses a database and I install that application on a new device,is it possible to also transfer the database to the new device (for example ,in the application itself have one option to send through blue tooth).

3.Is it possible to use a database other than sqlite database.

Answer (score 1):

1. Maximum size of database depends on the memory space available to the app.
2. When you will install app in new device it will create fresh database. There may be methods to receive the records from database in another device and save them in new device which is your implementation as in case of contacts ( you can send contacts from one device to another and save them ).
3. Yes , You can use other Database also but Android provides native support to only SQLite.
   [Does Android support any other database system other than SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143602/does-android-support-any-other-database-system-other-than-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

1) android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase has following method to getthe maximum size the database getMaximumSize().

2) Not possible . But from your application you can read the database and write it in SDCard, similarly you can read the database from the SDCard and replace the existing.

3) check this link [Does Android support any other database system other than SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143602/does-android-support-any-other-database-system-other-than-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

1. there is no such limit as to the size of the storage of data in the database. you can store as much data as there is free space available on the device.
2. The best way to share data amongst devices is by using a data backup to store data on the cloud and then retrieve the data from cloud to device. Refer to [data backup](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) for that.
3. I dont think any other database is supported by android. SQLite is a must. Although other databases like Amazons Simple DB do provide [android APIs](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/) to store data on the cloud. Also you can surely use remote databases to store data and make it accessible to other devices at the same time.