# How to create database in a dictionary application in Android?

Tags: android, database, performance, dictionary, offline

I want to make a Japanese dictionary application but I have no more experiences about Android programming.

How to create database to store data (such as words, means...). Can you give me some advice to create a database which is the most effective and fastest. (include How to do? Which I need to learn in Android programming)

Thanks you,

Comment: Lots of wants, no effort shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple ideas:

1. Create a web site or web API that interfaces with a database. Alternatively, find an already existing API from a third party. Then call the API from your app.
2. Preload all your data into the app from data files that you compile into the APK. This is less desirable if you expect your data to update on a regular basis. Or if your data is somewhat large.

Comment: Thanks you, I want to make an offline database. Can you give me an example.

Comment: I think idea 2 is better than idea 1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Try Installing an add-on called [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) in Firefox.

Its fastest and having good GUI

After installing this add-on you can create database very simply and that created database will be .sqlite extension(insertion,deletion& updation is very simple).
Paste it in ur project by making a folder name assets & inside it paste the created .sqlite

After that u can start on ur coding part & to learn more about sqlite visit this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Comment: thanks u so much. I will study. It is the best way or an other way?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143602/does-android-support-any-other-database-system-other-than-sqlite